# How to use dynamic dispatch with a method which takes an iterator as a parameter?

Tags: rust, iterator, traits, dynamic-dispatch

I am writing a command line application in rust for processing audio from a sensor. I would like the user to be able to choose an algorithm or filter to apply from several options. I was hoping to use dynamic dispatch to switch out a struct which implements my filter trait at runtime. However, this is not allowed by the compiler, because one of the trait methods takes a generic parameter.

How could I implement this same functionality, without causing any compiler troubles? I know that an easy solution is to change the parameter of the process method to an array or a vector, but this is my last resort, as I would much prefer to take an iterator or an IntoIterator, as it is more general, and suits my specific needs.

Here is some code which demonstrates the problem.

```
trait SensorFilter {
    fn process(&self, sig: &mut impl Iterator<Item = f32>) -> Vec<f32>;
}

struct Alg1 {
    mul: f32,
}

struct Alg2 {
    add: f32,
}

impl SensorFilter for Alg1 {
    fn process(&self, sig: &mut impl Iterator<Item = f32>) -> Vec<f32> {
        sig.map(|x| x * self.mul).collect()
    }
}

impl SensorFilter for Alg2 {
    fn process(&self, sig: &mut impl Iterator<Item = f32>) -> Vec<f32> {
        sig.map(|x| x * self.add).collect()
    }
}

enum AlgChoice {
    Alg1,
    Alg2
}

fn main() {
    let choice = AlgChoice::Alg1; // user chooses via command-line.
    let mut sig = vec![0.,1.,2.,3.,4.,5.,6.].into_iter(); // iterator gets data from sensor.

    // This doesn't work, because my trait cannot be made into an object.
    let alg: &dyn SensorFilter = match choice {
        AlgChoice::Alg1 => Alg1{mul:0.3},
        _ => Alg2{add:1.2},
    };

    let result = alg.process(&mut sig);
    println!("{:?}",result);
}
```

Thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The trick here is to change your generic function parameter to a generic trait parameter:

```
// Make the generic param into a type argument w/ constraints
trait SensorFilter<I> where I: Iterator<Item = f32> {
    fn process(&self, sig: &mut I) -> Vec<f32>;
}

struct Alg1 {
    mul: f32,
}

struct Alg2 {
    add: f32,
}

// Implement trait for all I that match the iterator constraint
impl<I: Iterator<Item = f32>> SensorFilter<I> for Alg1 {
    fn process(&self, sig: &mut I) -> Vec<f32> {
        sig.map(|x| x * self.mul).collect()
    }
}

impl<I: Iterator<Item = f32>> SensorFilter<I> for Alg2 {
    fn process(&self, sig: &mut I) -> Vec<f32> {
        sig.map(|x| x * self.add).collect()
    }
}

enum AlgChoice {
    Alg1,
    Alg2
}

fn main() {
    let choice = AlgChoice::Alg1; // user chooses via command-line.
    let mut sig = vec![0.,1.,2.,3.,4.,5.,6.].into_iter(); // iterator gets data from sensor.

    // Specify the type argument of your trait.
    let alg: &dyn SensorFilter<std::vec::IntoIter<f32>> = match choice {
        AlgChoice::Alg1 => &Alg1{mul:0.3},
        _ => &Alg2{add:1.2}, 
    };

    let result = alg.process(&mut sig);
    println!("{:?}",result);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to make `SensorFilter` object safe is to simply change `process` to accept `dyn Iterator` instead of `impl Iterator`:

```
trait SensorFilter {
    fn process(&self, sig: &mut dyn Iterator<Item = f32>) -> Vec<f32>;
}
```

If you couldn't do this, for example because `Iterator` were actually non-object-safe, you could instead extract the common, non-object-safe part into a second trait, and implement it automatically for everything that is `SensorFilter`:

```
// This trait is object-safe.
trait SensorFilter {
    fn filter(&self, x: f32) -> f32;
}

// This trait will not be object-safe because it uses generics.
trait Process {
    fn process<I: IntoIterator<Item = f32>>(&self, sig: I) -> Vec<f32>;
}

// The `?Sized` bound allows you to call `.process()` on `dyn SensorFilter`.
impl<T: ?Sized + SensorFilter> Process for T {
    fn process<I: IntoIterator<Item = f32>>(&self, sig: I) -> Vec<f32> {
        sig.into_iter().map(|x| self.filter(x)).collect()
    }
}

// ...

impl SensorFilter for Alg1 {
    fn filter(&self, x: f32) -> f32 {
        x * self.mul
    }
}

impl SensorFilter for Alg2 {
    fn filter(&self, x: f32) -> f32 {
        x * self.add
    }
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=35e2c33d1a7b52afbe44f1d57057e8b0)

Note that instead of `Iterator` I used `IntoIterator`, which is strictly more general.

A variation on this idea, when you can't easily remove the genericity from `SensorFilter`, is to use double dispatch: write `SensorFilter` to use `dyn Iterator` instead of `impl Iterator`, and then write a convenience trait that just wraps it with the specific type:

```
trait SensorFilter {
    fn process_dyn(&self, sig: &mut dyn Iterator<Item = f32>) -> Vec<f32>;
}

trait Process {
    fn process<I: IntoIterator<Item = f32>>(&self, sig: I) -> Vec<f32>;
}

impl<T: ?Sized + SensorFilter> Process for T {
    fn process<I: IntoIterator<Item = f32>>(&self, sig: I) -> Vec<f32> {
        self.process_dyn(&mut sig.into_iter())
    }
}
```